# Code in ViewWillAppear doesn't work, why?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

my app start with a tab bar controller, then every tab goes with a navigation VC. I wish to hide tab bar in the bottom whenever I start to navigate into a second VC, and also change the color of navigation bar to orange color, here's the code in the 2nd VC:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    var tabBarHide = self.tabBarController!.tabBar.hidden
    print(tabBarHide)
    if !tabBarHide {
        tabBarHide = true
    }
    print(tabBarHide)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.init(red: 247/255, green: 119/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1)

}
```

It does print out: false & true every time I navigate to this VC, but nothing happened to the view. It doesn't work. Why?

Comment: How are you assigning the value to `self.tabBarController`?

Comment: BTW, the code    "if !tabBarHide {         tabBarHide = true     }"  can be shortened by  "tabBarHide = true", and it's clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the `UIAppearance` proxy to alter the appearance of an object that is already in the view hierarchy.  From the [`UIAppearance` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIAppearance):

> iOS applies appearance changes when a view enters a window, it doesn’t change the appearance of a view that’s already in a window. To change the appearance of a view that’s currently in a window, remove the view from the view hierarchy and then put it back.

You can modify the tint color of the active navigation bar directly:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.init(red: 247/255, green: 119/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1)
```

As for why your tab bar isn't hiding, you are modifying your local variable, not the `hidden` property of the tab bar.  You want:

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = true
```

So your `viewWillAppear` should be something like:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = true
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.init(red: 247/255, green: 119/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1)

}
```

Comment: It seems .navigationBar.tintColor is the color of text, I want to change background color, then I tried .navigationBar.backgroundColor, it doesn't work D;

Comment: `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor` worked for me